# How to convert this Swift syntax into Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am converting a Swift Library into Objective-C as an exercise.

How to convert this into Objective-C ?

```
let formatter = NSDate.formatter(format: dateFormat)
```

I tried:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDate formatterWithFormat : dateFormat];
```

Also tried this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDate formatterWithFormat : dateFormat : [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] : [NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

Also tried this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDate formatter : dateFormat : [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] : [NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

Error: no know class method for selector "formatterWithFormat:" or "formatter :::"

More context:

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *) formatter : (NSString *) format  : (NSTimeZone*) timeZone  : (NSLocale *) locale {
    format = DefaultFormat;
    timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *hashKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu%lu%lu", (unsigned long)format.hash, (unsigned long)timeZone.hash, (unsigned long)locale.hash];
    NSMutableDictionary *formatters = [NSDate sharedDateFormatters];
    NSDateFormatter *cachedDateFormatter = formatters[hashKey];
    if (cachedDateFormatter != nil) {
        return cachedDateFormatter;
    }
    else {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        formatter.dateFormat = format;
        formatter.timeZone = timeZone;
        formatter.locale = locale;
        formatters[hashKey] = formatter;
        return formatter;
    }
}
```

*Some random text in-between so SO will let me add more code...*

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *)formatter:(NSDateFormatterStyle)dateStyle timeStyle:(NSDateFormatterStyle)timeStyle relativeDateFormatting:(BOOL)doesRelativeDateFormatting timeZone:(NSTimeZone *)timeZone locale:(NSLocale *)locale {
    timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *hashKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu", (unsigned long)dateStyle, (unsigned long)timeStyle, (unsigned long)doesRelativeDateFormatting, (unsigned long)timeZone.hash, (unsigned long)locale.hash];
    NSMutableDictionary *formatters = [NSDate sharedDateFormatters];
    NSDateFormatter *cachedDateFormatter = formatters[hashKey];
    if (cachedDateFormatter != nil) {
        return cachedDateFormatter;
    }
    else {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        formatter.dateStyle = dateStyle;
        formatter.timeStyle = timeStyle;
        formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = doesRelativeDateFormatting;
        formatter.timeZone = timeZone;
        formatter.locale = locale;
        formatters[hashKey] = formatter;
        return formatter;
    }
}
```

Original Swift code:

```
private class func formatter(format format:String = DefaultFormat, timeZone: NSTimeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone(), locale: NSLocale = NSLocale.currentLocale()) -> NSDateFormatter {
            let hashKey = "\(format.hashValue)\(timeZone.hashValue)\(locale.hashValue)"
            var formatters = NSDate.sharedDateFormatters()
            if let cachedDateFormatter = formatters[hashKey] {
                return cachedDateFormatter
            } else {
                let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = format
                formatter.timeZone = timeZone
                formatter.locale = locale
                formatters[hashKey] = formatter
                return formatter
            }
        }
```

*Some random text in-between so SO will let me add more code...*

```
private class func formatter(dateStyle dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle, timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle, doesRelativeDateFormatting: Bool, timeZone: NSTimeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone(), locale: NSLocale = NSLocale.currentLocale()) -> NSDateFormatter {
        var formatters = NSDate.sharedDateFormatters()
        let hashKey = "\(dateStyle.hashValue)\(timeStyle.hashValue)\(doesRelativeDateFormatting.hashValue)\(timeZone.hashValue)\(locale.hashValue)"
        if let cachedDateFormatter = formatters[hashKey] {
            return cachedDateFormatter
        } else {
            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateStyle = dateStyle
            formatter.timeStyle = timeStyle
            formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = doesRelativeDateFormatting
            formatter.timeZone = timeZone
            formatter.locale = locale
            formatters[hashKey] = formatter
            return formatter
        }
    }
```

Comment: If that's the method you are trying to call then you need to pass all 3 parameters, not just one.

Comment: And what's the point of having those three parameters being passed in if you simply override their values? You didn't use the code I gave you in your previous question.

Comment: Actually, I did. Let me add this to the question. Please keep in mind I am converting this from an existing Swift code and trying to keep it as similar as possible.

Comment: I removed the first two lines that set `timeZone` and `locale`. Those lines are pointless since you supply the desired values as parameters.

Comment: Still, you are getting the error because you are only pass one parameter instead of all the required parameters.

Comment: Why does it work in the Swift code ?

Comment: The swift code has default parameter values (which isn't supported by Objective-C).

Comment: Oh. Thx ! Please post this as answer and I accept it + upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on all your updates, the key difference between your Objective-C code and Swift code is that the Swift function provides default values for the parameters. This allows you to call the function (in this case) with zero or more arguments.

Since Objective-C doesn't support default parameter values, you need to pass a value for every parameter.

The method:

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *) formatter : (NSString *) format  : (NSTimeZone*) timeZone  : (NSLocale *) locale {
}
```

Needs to be called as:

```
[WhateverClassThisIs formatter:someFormat :someTimeZone :someLocale];
```

Note the ugly syntax due to you not naming all of the parameters (like I showed in your previous question.

You also need to remove the lines you added to assign values to those parameters at the start of the method.

Comment: Ok, I tried this: NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDate formatterWithFormat : dateFormat : [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] : [NSLocale currentLocale]]; but I still get the same error.

Comment: BTW (and please take this as the helpful, constructive comment it is meant to be) - given all the questions you've asked the last couple of days, I strongly urge you find a good tutorial on the Objective-C programming language. Time spent learning the syntax now will save you a ton of time as you move forward.

Comment: Hahahah ! Actually, I am specifically converting a Swift Library to Objective-C to learn the syntax (after some tutorials and an entire course). But thx for the comment !

Comment: BTW: still doesn't work. NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDate formatter : dateFormat : [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] : [NSLocale currentLocale]];

Comment: What class did you add this `+formatter:::` method to?

Comment: I added it to NSDate (method is part of a category)

Comment: And of the two Objective-C implementations you posted in your question, which of the two do you really have in your `NSDate` category? And does the declaration in the .h file match the implementation in the .m file?

Comment: What was your final fix?

Comment: It was the .h file  As always, one may forget to check the simplest fixes first ^^

Answer (score 2):

Your conversion of the syntax is syntactically correct.

However, `NSDate` does not offer a static method called `formatterWithFormat:` or `formatter`; it appears that the code from which you are translating has an *extension* method for that. You need to locate that method, and translate it instead.

Note: I would strongly recommend *against* making it an extension on `NSDate`, because it belongs to `NSDateFormatter` side of class hierarchy.

Comment: I agree with the note. It makes no sense to have such a method on the `NSDate` class.

Comment: I think I need to provide more context. I will edit my question.